# How to save an array of objects to mongoose DB with only one call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to save an array of JSON object to a mongodb with only **one** call?
something like:

```
schemeObject.save(array_of_json_object, callback);
```

I'm using `mongoosejs`

Comment: Can you please update the correct answer?

Comment: @IcyFlame Your linked post is technically a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @DanMandle right! I didn't notice the dates. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726330/mongoose-mongodb-batch-insert

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not think its possible with mongooosejs. You can however use BATCH insert of mongodb ,which is supported natively.

Helpful links:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongoose-orm/IkPmvcd0kds/bZuYCN_orckJ

Comment: the answer is found in the second link. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

There is a way to batch insert with MongooseJS. I'm not sure if it's a new feature since this question was asked/answered, but I figured if someone were to come here from a search, they should know the way to do it.

```
var array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }];
Candy.create(array, function (err, jellybean, snickers) {
  if (err) // ...
});
```

Here are the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

Comment: That should work if we want to create new docs. How about update a array or docs that returned from a query?

Comment: For that, I think you'd have to do a find() then a forEach() on the result, update the values and do a save() for each of them. But I'm pretty new to Mongoose myself.

Answer (score 2):

**This works with mongoose as well**

```
Laptop.insertMany(laptopData, function (err, laptop) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  };
  console.log(laptop);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? I know it loops through the entire array.. dont ask me about the Big O for this.. probably not the best way to insert but works for just an initial data dump of some sort..

```
var arr = // array of objects;
    res = [];

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    item.save(function (err) {
        res.push(err);
        if (res.length === arr.length)
        {
            // Done
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that woudnt be a batch insert if its one by one!

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that I've used. If you are using mongoose with promises, you can do this using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

You can start using Q as the default promise for mongoose using the below code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
```

Then you can save an array of documents like below. Let's say we are storing an array of User models, which I've shown in `users` variable.

```
Q
  .all(users.map(curr => curr.save()))
  .then((results) => { //do something })
  .catch((err) => { //handle error })
```

`.save()` will return a `q` promise and using array `map` function, we'll create a promise array using the user models array.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution instead of using

```
new model_name({
your data
})
```

use this

```
model_name.create({your data}).then(res).catch(err)
```

// simple promise things