# Mongoose: what's the differences between Model.create and Collection.insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, mongoose

I want do a batch insert job in MongoDB and I found two ways in mongoose:

One way is use `insert`:

```
dataArr = [
   {
       id: "",
       name: ""
   }
   {
       id: "",
       name: ""
   }
]
```

`Collection.insert(dataArr)`

and another way is `Model.create`:

```
Model.create(dataArr)
```

both could complete the batch insert job, but what's the difference between them?

Which one is more  efficiency?

Comment: I'm always a big supporter of actually diving in and tracing through the code. It's one of the biggest benefits to open source.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24848148/778272) to a previous question regarding differences in **performance** of both approaches.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Mongoose, there is [`Model.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) and [`Collection.insert`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#collection_Collection-insert) (the latter isn't strictly part of Mongoose, but of the underlying MongoDB driver).

According to the Mongoose developer, they are [basically the same](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/723#issuecomment-13267429) when called with an array of documents, although looking at the code makes me think that there are subtle differences (**warning**: I haven't looked at the code *that* well so I might be mistaken about the following):

- using `Model.create` will call any validators/hooks declared on your schema;
- `Model.create` does a `.save` for each document in the array, resulting in `N` database calls (where `N` is the number of documents in the array); `Collection.insert` performs one large database call;

Comment: As of Mongoose v3.8.12, ``Model.collection.insert`` runs **much** faster than ``Model.create``. You should take it into account if doing bulk inserts. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24848148/778272.

Comment: Can you give a real live example with this method. Using `Model.collection` in my code does nothing. Defining your collection in the mongoos schema with {collection: 'myName'} works, but accessing it, don't.

Comment: There's another important difference worth being aware about. `Model.create` when validating will also convert string ObjectId's to actual ObjectId's if the schema specifies it as the type of the field, whereas `Model.collection.insert` does not so it will insert strings as plain strings.

Comment: @AdamBuczynski good point. Basically, by using the underlying MongoDB driver a lot of what Mongoose offers will be circumvented (which explains why it's much faster, but it _is_ something to be aware of).

Answer (score 1):

according to what i've read, Collection.insert is a function of mongoDB driver it's much faster when inserting big amounts of data like millions or such at the cost that it bypasses mongoose validations.

handle with care

Comment: please add this answer under the post, not as an answer

Comment: i can't add it as a comment , that's why I answered here

Comment: you don't have the option `add a comment` under all comments of the original post ?

Comment: yes, but it's not available for me , i mean i see add a comment but i can't add until i have reputation

Answer (score 0):

They loosely mean the same thing. You can use either of them.

Answer (score 0):

checking the documentation for `insertMany`, apparently it's faster that `create` as  it only sends one operation to the server, rather than one for each document.

insertMany [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-insertMany), one thing to note is that insertMany does not trigger save middleware, while on the other hand, `create` does.