# inserting or saving into mongodb returns 500 server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi i am trying to build an crud app using the mean stack. On load the express application successfully retrieves the "contactlist" collection from the database. However when attempting to post to "/api/contacts"... an error 500 is recieved (TypeError: undefined is not a function). I have roamed countless blogs/forums in search of a solution, however now i am lost and yet to pin point the source behind the error. Please all suggestions are welcome.

Following is the full error stack...

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at module.exports.postcontactlist (/Users/Sites/express/api/contacts.js:22:11)
    at callbacks (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Users/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:48:5)
    at next (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.urlencoded [as handle] (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:46:27)
    at next (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at /Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:91:7
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Sites/express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:57:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
POST /api/contacts 500 4ms - 1.69kb
```

Here is my code:

//Server.js

```
var contactlist = require("./api/contacts");
....
//server
app.get("/api/contacts", contactlist.getcontactlist);
app.post("/api/contacts", contactlist.postcontactlist);
```

//api/contacts.js

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var bp = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var schema = require("../models/contactsdb"); 

var Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", schema.contactSchema, "contactlist");

module.exports = {

    getcontactlist : function (request, response) { 

        Contact.find({ }, function (err, docs) { 
            response.send(docs);
        });

    },
    postcontactlist : function(request, response){

        console.log("request: " + request.body);


        Contact.insert({ name : "Vincent Moyet", email : "vincentmoyet@gmail.com", number : "0987654321" }, function(err, docs){

            if(err){
                var errorMsg = "error: " + err.message;
                console.log(errorMsg + " / " + err.getLastError());
                response.status(500).send(err);

            } else {
                console.log("success");
                response.status(200).end();
            }

        });

    }

};
```

///models/contactsBb

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); 

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist');

exports.contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    number: String
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function from `insert` to `create`

```
Contact.create(contact, function(err, docs){    
    if(err){
        var errorMsg = "error: " + err.message;
        console.log(errorMsg + " / " + err.getLastError());
        response.status(500).send(err);    
    } else {
        console.log("success");
        response.status(200).end();
    }

});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! that worked!! 
Still im baffled why "insert" or "save" don't work?? please canyou explain so i can fully understand?

Comment: Dont worry found an aswer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701154/mongoose-whats-the-differences-between-model-create-and-collection-insert