# Bulk operation by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I want to store bulk data (more than 1000 or 10000 records) in a single operation by MongoOSE. But MongoOSE does not support bulk operations so I will use the native driver (MongoDB, for insertion). I know that I will bypass all MongoOSE middlewares but its ok. (Please correct me If I am wrong! :) )

I have an option to store data by `insert` method. But MongoDB also provides Bulk class (ordered and unordered operations). Now I have the following questions:

- Difference between `insert` and `bulk` operation (both can store bulk data) ?
- Any specific difference between `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` (performs operation in serially) and `initializeOrderedBulkOp()` (performs operations in parallel) ?
- <s>If I will use `initializeUnorderedBulkOp` then it will effect on by range search or any side-effects ?</s>
- Can I do it by Promisification (by BlueBird) ?? (I am trying to do it.)

Thanks

EDIT: I am talking about `bulk` vs `insert` regarding to multiple insertions. Which one is better? Insertion one by one by bulk builder OR insertion by batches (1000) in insert method. I hope now it will clear  [Mongoose (mongodb) batch insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726330/mongoose-mongodb-batch-insert) this link

Comment: While MongooseJS does have a bulk save via [`Model.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) it is actually creating individual save statements (which will use the middleware) and then using `async.parallel` to execute them. So if you are doing large bulk saves then you might want to use `Model.collection.insert()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose (mongodb) batch insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726330/mongoose-mongodb-batch-insert)

Comment: mongoose has [`Model.bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite).

Answer (score 17):

If you are calling this from a mongoose model you need the `.collection` accessor

```
var bulk = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// examples
bulk.insert({ "a": 1 });
bulk.find({ "a": 1 }).updateOne({ "$set": { "a": 2 } });

bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
   // result contains stats of the operations
});
```

You need to be "careful" when doing this though. Apart from not being bound to the same checks and validation that can be attached to mongoose schemas, when you call `.collection` you need to be "sure" that the connection to the database has already been made. Mongoose methods look after this for you, but once you use the underlying driver methods you are all on your own.

As for diffferences it's all there in the naming:

- **Ordered**: Means that the batched instructions are executed in the same order they are added. They execute one after the other in sequence and one at a time. If an error occurs at any point, the execution of the batch is halted and the error response returned. All operations up until then are "comitted". This is **not** a rollback.
- **UnOrdered**: Means that batched operations can execute in "any" sequence and often in parallel. This can lead to faster updates, but of course cannot be used where one bulk operation in the batch is meant to occur before another ( example above ). Any errors that occur are merely "reported" in the result, and the whole batch will complete as sent to the server.

Of course the core difference for either type of execution from the standard methods is that the "whole batch" ( actually in lots of 1000 maximum ) is sent to the server and you only get one response back. This saves network traffic and waiting for each idividual `.insert()` or other like operation to complete.

As for can a "promise" be used, well anything else with a callback that you can convert to returning a promise follows the same rules as here. Remember though that the "callback/promise" is on the `.execute()` method, and that what you get back complies to the rules of what is returned from Bulk operations results.

For more information see ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) in the core documentation.

Comment: Well explained.