# How do I use insertMany with Mongoose when I have a big array of object?

Tags: mongoose, promise

I'm trying to use the insertMany method, but without success... I read this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35174701/4275509), but it does not tell how to do handle array of objects that are very big.

In my test case I have 9755 objects, with this script it imports all lines 9 times, which is not what I want...

I would like to dive the array in chunks of 1000 objects for each import.

How can I do this?

```
function bulkImportToMongo(arrayToImport, mongooseModel) {
  const Model = require(`../../../models/${mongooseModel}`);
  let counter = 0;
  let temp = [];
  arrayToImport.forEach(item => {
    temp.push(item);
    counter++;

    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
      Model.insertMany(temp).then(mongoosedocs => {
        console.log(`imported ${counter} objects`);
        console.log(mongoosedocs.length);
        temp = [];
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of batches (each batch with no more than 100 elements). For each batch call `Model.insertMany`. To wait until all documents have been inserted, you `Promise.all`:

```
function bulkImportToMongo(arrayToImport, mongooseModel) {
  const Model = require(`../../../models/${mongooseModel}`);
  const batchSize = 100;
  let batchCount = Math.ceil(arrayToImport.length / batchSize);
  let recordsLeft = arrayToImport.length;
  let ops = [];
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < batchCount; i++) {
    let batch = arrayToImport.slice(counter, counter + batchSize);
    counter += batchSize;
    ops.push(Model.insertMany(batch));
  }
  return Promise.all(ops);
}
```

Comment: Unhandled rejection SyntaxError: Identifier 'batch' has already been declared. Should i remove "let batch ="?

Comment: No, I've fixed the example.

Comment: Thank you! Still not working for me. :-(. Here is the complete code if you have time to have a look.. https://repl.it/LdUd/5

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fix all bugs in your code, you asked the question about the concrete problem, I've provided the answer.

Comment: Found one issue in your code example, fix `batchSize` in `Math.ceil`, instead of 1000, use 100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155333/discussion-between-isak-la-fleur-and-alexmac).