# Multiple user creation in Passport, mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

How to register multiple users using csv uploader in Mongoose, nodejs, passport

````
    var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    console.log(data);
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        User.register(new User(data[i]),
            data[i].mobile,
            function (err, user) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error: err                       
                    });
                }
            });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Registration Successful!'
    });
};```
````

Comment: Try batch insert instead of inserting each entry. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35174701/2861108

Comment: Put register function in User model