# Save array of object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, astronomy

I want to save array of objects in MongoDB in my Meteor app and I'm also using Meteor astronomy for manage Mongo collection

My array of objects like this

```
[
    {
        "id" : "aaaa1",
        "make" : "toyota",
        "year" : "2005",
        "model" : "prado",
    },
    {
        "id" : "aaaa2",
        "make" : "toyota",
        "year" : "2005;2006",
        "model" : "fortuner",
    },
    {
        "id" : "aaaa3",
        "make" : "toyota",
        "year" : "2005;2006;2007;2008",
        "model" : "axio",

    },

]
```

I used map function to loop through the array and save data, but it only saves the last record. Here is my code

```
array.map((row) => {
  console.log(row.type);
  vehicleDb.set({
    make: row.make,
    year: row.year,
    model: row.model,

  });
  vehicleDb.save( function (error) {
    // console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an array of objects to mongoose DB with only one call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987359/how-to-save-an-array-of-objects-to-mongoose-db-with-only-one-call)

Comment: can you show your schema?

Comment: @sss That question is about Mongoose, not the MongoDB API provided by Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ".set" to save elements into an array, you need to "push" then into the array.
Here's a list of MongoDB array operators: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `vehicleDb` is your schema/model because you used `vehicleDb.save`. If my assumption is correct then you can try it:

```
array.map((row) => {
  console.log(row);
  var newVehicle = new vehicleDb(row);
  newVehicle.save( function (error, doc) {
    // console.log(error);
    // console.log(doc)
  });
});
```

if `vehicleDb` is not your model then added your schema in your question and I  will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
array.map(async (row) => {
  const Notify = new Notification({ attributeName:row.attributeName, attributeName:row.attributeName})
  var save=await Notify.save()
});
```

In my case it is not working when passing a whole object for saving in a document.