# mongoose insert each in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am attempting to insert an array

Here is my schema:

```
/**
 * Created by root on 12/4/16.
 */
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
    var hotPrice = mongoose.Schema({
        days: String,
        price: String
    });

    return mongoose.model('hotPrice', hotPrice);
};
```

And here is my route:

```
router.route('/createHot')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var values = [
            {days: 1, price: "63"},
            {days: 2, price: "125"},
            {days: 3, price: "185"},
            {days: 4, price: "250"},
            {days: 5, price: "314"},
            {days: 6, price: "375"},
            {days: 7, price: "425"},
            {days: 8, price: "495"},
            {days: 9, price: "560"},
            {days: 10, price: "620"}
        ];
        mongoose.models.hotPrice(values).insert(function (err, message) {
            res.status(200);
        });
    });
```

However i get the following:

```
TypeError: mongoose.models.hotPrice(...).insert is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me how i can bulk insert this array?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

You can do as follows: (using the example of mongoose docs)

```
// pass an array
var values = [
            {days: 1, price: "63"},
            {days: 2, price: "125"},
            {days: 3, price: "185"},
            {days: 4, price: "250"},
            {days: 5, price: "314"},
            {days: 6, price: "375"},
            {days: 7, price: "425"},
            {days: 8, price: "495"},
            {days: 9, price: "560"},
            {days: 10, price: "620"}
        ];
YourSchemeObject.create(values, function (err, values) {
  if (err) // ...

})
```

You also can find a similar question here:

[How to save an array of objects to mongoose DB with only one call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987359/how-to-save-an-array-of-objects-to-mongoose-db-with-only-one-call)

Hope it helps.